# Decode a PHP serialized value in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, serialization, decode, encode

Just a quick question. Is there a built in function to decode a PHP serialized value in Javascript or jQuery? A have a PHP serialized array stored in a database and this is sent via AJAX to the page.

Preferably I need to decode this array in Javascript, is there a function for this or does the PHP serialize function use it's own format that would involve reg expressions and the such to decode? If so I'll just change it in PHP to JSON before I send over I guess.

Thanks for any advice in advance

Comment: Use `json_encode` to encode it to JSON in PHP, and send that to JavaScript.

Comment: `unserialize` first then `json_encode` as Bart suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert it to JSON in PHP.